# PhoneGap Build and OneSignal - Ios Certificates and Provisioning profiles

Tags: phonegap-build, provisioning-profile, onesignal, phonegap

I have used OneSignals Provisonator to generate a .p12 and .cer file.
The problem comes when I have to upload the certificate to PhoneGap build, because PhoneGap Build also wants a Provisioning Profile.

On the Apple Developer website, I create a provisioning profile but I do not see the certificate created by the provisonator.

I have no idea how to create it using the certificate created previously. Also because the Provisonator does not give me a .csr file :(

Any help...PLEASEEEE!!

Comment: Hi, please read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers. I believe this question is not related to coding in general, could you rephrase it to better fit what is indicated in the above links?

Comment: Check the PhoneGap Build docs. They explain exactly how you do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OneSignal's Provisionator is used to generate a certificate for push notifications, not for code signing apps. You need separate code signing certificate for development and distribution.  You cannot set up a provisioning profile with an APNS (Apple Push Notification Service) certificate.

If you look in the [Phonegap documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap-build/signing/ios/), it will explain how to set up your code signing.